# change silent mode for alert

Tags: android, alert, alarm, ringtone, silent

I am using alert in my app. If silent mode is enable, alert doesn't work. How can I change silent mode for my alert. Also, how can I learn whether  alert(music etc.) is finished. Thanks in advance.

```
private void mediaPlayerStart()
{
    try
    {
        Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if(alert == null)
        {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            if(alert == null)
            {
                alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        }
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
        ringtone.play();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setStreamType solved my problem.

```
 ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
 ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
 ringtone.play();
```